# SyntaxProblem when using SublimeText REPL

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I have been learning python3 recently.
There is a problem when I try to use Sublime REPL to interpret my codes and I haven't figured out how to solve it. Much appreciate it if someone can help me!

When I try to write a simple input statement, everything works fine with the SublimeText REPL interpreter.

```
number1 = input('number1')
number2 = input('number2')
print(number1)
```

But there is a syntax error when I try to print the result. I could not find any syntax error by myself since I am following the book .
Codes as shown below:

```
number1 = input('number1')
number2 = input('number2')
result = int(number1) - int(number2)
print(f'Number1 - Number2 = {result}')
```

Here is the error:

```
File "test.py", line 4
print(f'Number1 - Number2 = {result}')
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

edit:
When I type on SublimeText:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

The output is
`3.9.7 (v3.9.7:1016ef3790, Aug 30 2021, 16:39:15)`

I assume maybe SublimeText REPL is not running the latest version. Does anyone know how to update the REPL python version?

Comment: which python version are you running? f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6.

Comment: Hi djinn, I am using python 3.9.7.

Comment: You perhaps have Python 3.9.7 installed on your system, but that's not what's running this code.  Only a version prior to 3.6 would produce this error.

Comment: Hi Jason, I typed print(sys.version) in sublimeText and it told me that its 3.9.7. Maybe REPL is not using current version of python?

Comment: Do you have any other versions of Python besides 3.9.7 installed on your system?

Comment: Perhaps this can help you out https://coderwall.com/p/nhq2gg/setting-up-sublimerepl-with-python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved, thanks to @alec_djinn and the community.

In my case, I followed the steps from [coderwall.com/p/nhq2gg/setting-up-sublimerepl-with-python3](http://coderwall.com/p/nhq2gg/setting-up-sublimerepl-with-python3)

It seems the syntax error occurs because of SublimeText REPL is not running the correct version of python that was installed in the system.

Comment: Please include the steps that you took to solve the problem within your answer.